# In Xcode 11.3 storyboard and nib size is almost double

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11.3

The .nib files and the storyboard files binary generated via Xcode 11.3 is almost double than those generated by Xcode 10.1. This increases the size of the app.

The size increase is due to nib file has two formats
The .nib files binary generated via **XCode 11.3** is almost double than those generated by Xcode 10.1
This increases the size of the app generated for adhoc download.

The size increase is due to nib file has two formats:

**objects-11.0+.nib
objects-13.0+.nib**

runtime.nib

do we have any option to disable the settings from generation 2 architecture?